# Schema formation using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Need to form schema in mongoose for the following json, also "additional" object can contain more than one property.

```
{
 "_id": "key",
 "status": "active",
 "additional": {
    "First": {
        "name": "First Name"
    },
    "Last": {
        "name": "Last Name"
    }
  }
}
```

I came up with the following, but want "additional" to be another schema (subdocument). As i need to use mongoose validations on subdocument too.

```
let schema = new Schema({
_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
status: {
    type: String,
    default: true
},
additional: {
    type: Object
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Embedded Objects in Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html)

your code would look like something like this:

```
var Name = new Schema({
    name     : String
});

let schema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
    additional: {
        First: Name,
        Last: Name
    }
});
```

For dynamic properties, first you need to store name and types of these properties in a seprate table, e.g NameProperty. then your code would be something like this:

```
var Name = new Schema({
    name     : String
});

var props = db.NameProperty.find();
props.map(function(prop){
    Name[prop.name] = prop.type
})

let schema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
    additional: {
        First: Name,
        Last: Name
    }
});
```

Comment: but additional object can have any property, cannot pre decide while defining schema.But it is sure, that property will have "name" in it

Comment: you can put those properties in your schema! mongo would not store them as long as they're null.

Comment: Also if your properties are fully dynamic, you can store those labels in an other collection, load that collection and then create this schema from it!

Comment: Yes, properties are fully dynamic.is there any solution without creating another collection

Comment: I added a sample to the answer :)